# As an indie developer, what do I put in the contact section of the "Agreements, Tax, and Banking" in iTunes connect?

Tags: app-store-connect, developer-program, in-app-purchase

Not quite sure if this is the place to ask but I'm trying to set up IAPs in my app so I need to fill out the paid contract first. I have no idea exactly *who* I'm supposed to put in my contact section.

I'm not a company, and I do not have any people that serve Senior Management, Financial, Technical, Legal, Marketing roles. I need to fill this section out to continue but am stumped as to what exactly I'm supposed to put here.

Answer (score 2):

I just put myself. I'm a student and the sole person with any responsibility for the apps on the account, so I simply put myself. I had no issues with this.